# Strange error when building R packages for Windows

Tags: windows, r

On one of my PCs, when I build any R package I get the following fatal error

```
* checking for file 'forecast/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'forecast':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* removing junk files
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building binary distribution
WARNING: some HTML links may not be found
Error in setwd(owd) : cannot change working directory
 ERROR
* installation failed
```

But the same packages compile fine on my other PC. I'm at a loss as to what's causing this. Has anyone else seen something similar?

Using Windows XP, R2.10.1, Rtools 2.10.

Comment: Tricky question. Maybe something else in the PATH?  Do you use a directories or path with spaces?

Comment: I've never seen that before.  Dirk's suggestion is a good one: maybe compare the PATH on both machines.  Alternatively, could it be an issue with permissions on a given directory (maybe the process doing the build doesn't have access to everything)?  Are the installations the same on both machines (same version of R, etc.)?

Comment: I take it that you figured this one out given that you submitted forcast 2.02 to CRAN today?

Comment: Does the owd directory exists on the machine that causes problems?

Comment: Software versions and paths the same on both machines.
owd is a variable name rather than a directory, presumably in the perl scripts somewhere.
Shane: no, I've been using the machine that worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the problem. I had set the variable `.Library.site` in the file `Rprofile.site` on one machine to point to a non-existent directory. It never affected R for normal use, but showed up when I tried to compile a package.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Please show me how you did set the variable `.Library.site` on `Windows 10`?